# Understanding a proof of a result of Schofield

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, quivers

I'm reading a paper of Aidan Schofield- "General Representations of Quivers" and I'm trying to understand the proof of Theorem 3.3. I'm having trouble understanding the argument that's underlined in the below image:[image]

I don't understand why is it possible to find a point in the general fibre such the dimension of the tangent space at this point will be $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$. I don't know if it has got anything to do with generic smoothness. Even if it does, I don't understand how to use it here.

I would greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: This is indeed just generic smoothness. The source of the map is reduced, so it has a smooth dense open subset and the intersection of a general fibre with this open set will be smooth (by generic smoothness).

Comment: @naf Thanks for your comment. As I mentioned in the post, I don't understand very well why I can use generic smoothness. I looked at the generic smoothness in David Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra book and it had some technical conditions that I don't understand why it is applicable here. Can you please elaborate why you think we can use generic smoothness here in this setting. I would really appreciate your help and patience!!

Comment: I assume the base field is $\mathbb{C}$ in the paper, otherwise one cannot immediately use generic smoothness. Assuming this, we are in the $\mathrm{char} k = 0$ of Eisenbud's Cor 16.23. All local rings of a smooth variety are regular so the other assumption there will be satisfied once you restrict to a suitable open subset of the source.

Comment: For a discussion about Schofield's proof, and way to recover the result in positive characteristic, see W. Crawley-Boevey, Subrepresentations of general representations of quivers, Bull. London Math. Soc. 28 (1996), 363-366, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1384823